# c# search in list for two string in the same line

Tags: c#, list, search

i have a list named simple and all its objects are in the form below:

```
Tag:  textbook - sacred texts   Rec Id: 10011095 
Tag:  advocacy  Rec Id: 10037815 
Tag:  advocacy  Rec Id: 10043396 
Tag:  advocacy  Rec Id: 10037795 
Tag:  advocacy  Rec Id: 10031437 
Tag:  advocacy  Rec Id: 10035721 
Tag:  advocacy  Rec Id: 10024853
```

and i have a second list called fullList with objects like:

```
10055853    What's the Matter with the Internet? by Mark Poster      academic    1       0,083

10055853    What's the Matter with the Internet? by Mark Poster      computers       1       0,083

10055853    What's the Matter with the Internet? by Mark Poster      internet    2       0,167
```

i split every line of the simpe list in order to get two strings.
The first one has the word(s) after "Tag:" and before "Rec Id:" and the second the numbers after Rec id.

```
Example: tagGB  = textbook - sacred texts
rec_idGB = 10011095
```

And then i want to search if there IS'NT any line(object) from list fullList that contains BOTH (in the same line) that two strings.

I tried that:

```
 foreach (String line in nonZeroList)
        {

            foreach (String line2 in Gblist)
            {

            rec_idGB = line.Split('\t')[0].Substring(4).Trim();
            tagGB = line.Split('\t')[2].Substring(7).Trim();

            if (line.Contains(rec_idGB) == false && line.Contains(tagGB) == false)
            {

            }


        }
    }
```

but i get a lot of lines that doesnt contain that strings. 
I want to get as a resutl only the rec_idGB and tagGB that are not BOTH in the same line of the fullList. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get as a resutl only the rec_idGB and tagGB that are not BOTH in the same line of the fullList.

So you want all lines in simpleList that can't be matched with any line in fullList? (Or do you want for each line in fullList get all lines in simpleList that doesn't match? I **guess** not.)

```
foreach (string line in simpleList)
{
    string rec_idGB = line.Split('\t')[0].Substring(4).Trim();
    string tagGB = line.Split('\t')[2].Substring(7).Trim();
    bool thereIsAMatch = false;
    foreach (string line2 in fullList)
    {
        if (line2.Contains(rec_idGB) && line2.Contains(tagGB))
        {
            thereIsAMatch = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!thereIsAMatch)
    {
        // This is what you want?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try mine thread about this:
[filtering values from string after/before certain word in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268736/filtering-values-from-string-after-before-certain-word-in-c-sharp)

The solution was to use regular expressions

Not exactly the same problem, but I think you'll find out the solution easily as I did

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be comparing against `line2` instead of `line`?  Your parsing out from `line` and then checking if it is contained in `line` which you just parsed it out of.

Eg:

```
 if (line2.Contains(rec_idGB) == false && line2.Contains(tagGB) == false)
```

Or it could be the other way around... you want to parse from `line2` and compare to `line`, not really sure.